# MySQL, PHPMyAdmin - table column not accepting Decimal Datatype Length

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a table named **users**. It has two columns, `user_id` and `balance`. For balance column the datatype is `Decimal` and the length is `8,2`. I inserted these values while table creation. However, when I review the table structure for the `balance` column, I'm getting the `Decimal` length as '8,0' and not '8,2'. Can anyone explain why this is happening ?

[image: Table Creation]
[image: Table Review]

Comment: By the way, I am using WAMP server

Comment: Is PHPMyAdmin up-to-date? What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: My current version of PHPMyAdmin is 4.6.4 and MySQL is 5.7.14

Comment: Can I suggest that you upgrade your phpMyAdmin. You can find the latest version in the [WAMPServer backup repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) it is version 4.7.2 Or from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Applications/)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour. What does phpmyadmin show if you click the preview sql button?

Comment: As suggested by you guys I updated the WAMP server and PHPMyAdmin to their latest versions 3.0.9 and 4.7.2 respectively. I edited the format of `balance` column again and I am happy to inform that the right length`(8,2)` is being shown up when I review the table structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read from the comments, all you have to do is update PHPMyAdmin to its latest version. Once that is done, the column of the table accepts the mentioned length for the `Decimal` Datatype.